# How do I read a response from Python Requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have two Python scripts. One uses the [Urllib2 library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and one uses the [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

I have found Requests easier to implement, but I can't find an equivalent for urlib2's `read()` function. For example:

```
...
response = url.urlopen(req)
print response.geturl()
print response.getcode()
data = response.read()
print data
```

Once I have built up my post url, `data = response.read()` gives me the content - I am trying to connect to a vcloud director api instance and the response shows the endpoints that I have access to. However if I use the Requests library as follows.....

```
....

def post_call(username, org, password, key, secret):

    endpoint = '<URL ENDPOINT>'
    post_url = endpoint + 'sessions'
    get_url = endpoint + 'org'
    headers = {'Accept':'application/*+xml;version=5.1', \
               'Authorization':'Basic  '+ base64.b64encode(username + "@" + org + ":" + password), \
               'x-id-sec':base64.b64encode(key + ":" + secret)}
    print headers
    post_call = requests.post(post_url, data=None, headers = headers)
    print post_call, "POST call"
    print post_call.text, "TEXT"
    print post_call.content, "CONTENT"
    post_call.status_code, "STATUS CODE"

....
```

....the `print post_call.text` and `print post_call.content` returns nothing, even though the status code equals 200 in the requests post call.

Why isn't my response from Requests returning any text or content?

Comment: Do you know the type of response you should get from the URL? Json, xml, etc?

What is the response you are getting from urllib2?

Comment: The POST request may be returning a redirect response. Check the response headers: `post_call.headers`

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Requests doesn't have an equivalent to Urlib2's `read()`.

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
>>> print response.content
'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><head>....'
>>> print response.content == response.text
True
```

It looks like the POST request you are making is returning no content. Which is often the case with a POST request. Perhaps it set a cookie? The status code is telling you that the POST succeeded after all.

**Edit for Python 3:**

[Python now handles data types differently](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range). `response.content` returns a sequence of `bytes` (integers that represent ASCII) while `response.text` is a `string` (sequence of chars).

Thus,

```py
>>> print response.content == response.text
False

>>> print str(response.content) == response.text
True
```

Comment: ok - thanks. Maybe i'm getting confused somewhere. urllib2 shows me content so I need to understand what I am doing wrong and the different calls between the 2 libraries.

Comment: At a certain endpoint I want to read the request but I'm unable to using requests.get("url"). Moreover it takes unreasonable time to execute. Giving no arguments also throws an error saying 1 argument needed.

Comment: Check the response code. You're probably getting a timeout rather than a 2XX response. That would explain why it takes such a long time as well.

Comment: In Python 3, `response.content` is a `Bytes` instance, and `response.text` is `str`, so they will no longer compare equal directly (but decoding `response.content` with the correct encoding should return `response.text`

Answer (score 70):

If the response is in json you could do something like (python3):

```
import json
import requests as reqs

# Make the HTTP request.
response = reqs.get('https://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/group_list')

# Use the json module to load CKAN's response into a dictionary.
response_dict = json.loads(response.text)

for i in response_dict:
    print("key: ", i, "val: ", response_dict[i])
```

---

To see everything in the response you can use `.__dict__`:

```
print(response.__dict__)
```

Comment: You can "pretty print" this way too, using;
print(json.dumps(response_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

Answer (score 12):

If you push, for example image, to some API and want the result address(response) back you could do:

```
import requests
url = 'https://uguu.se/api.php?d=upload-tool'
data = {"name": filename}
files = {'file': open(full_file_path, 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
current_url = response.text
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 8):

If the Response is in Json you can directly use below method in Python3, no need for `json import` and `json.loads()` method:

```
response.json()
```

Answer (score 5):

There are three different ways for you to get the contents of the response you have got.

1. Content - (`response.content`) - libraries like `beautifulsoup` accept input as binary
2. JSON (`response.json()`) - most of the API calls give response in this format only
3. Text (`response.text`) - serves any purpose including regex based search, or dumping data to a file etc.

Depending the type of webpage you are scraping, you can use the attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To read any particular JSON entity, you can use this

```
response.get('id') or response.get('expected fields to be read')
```