# How to view Terminal output when running Requests in Python?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a simple Python scripts that POSTs a local file to a given URL via Requests:

```
import requests

url = 'http://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension'

files = {'file': open("myLocalFile.csv")}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)

print r.headers
```

When I run a cURL command in Terminal that does the exact same thing:

```
curl -k -F docfile=@myLocalFile.csv http://myWebsite.com/extension/extension/extension
```

I get the output:

```
{"success":true, "data":{"uploaded":39, "errors":0, "unchanged":39, "skipped":0, "updated":0, "created":0, "failed":[]}, "numRows":1}
```

which indicates that I have successfully uploaded the file. How can I view this same output when I run my python script? I want to be able to parse through this output and check to see if "success" is true/false.

Sorry for the weird formatting, I tried to fix it but couldn't :(

Comment: Theres a quickstart for the requests module: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print r.text
```

gives you the response body and then you can parse through the response body to check if success=true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Not having used the library before the example on their home page seems helpful
[python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).
More specifically:

```
print(r.json()) #possibly print(r.content)
# prints {u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810777/reading-the-response-in-python-requests)