# Is there a way to extract the http response using python polling function

Tags: python, http, publish-subscribe, polling

I was using following code to poll a pub/sub server

```
    import requests
    polling2.poll(lambda: requests.get('http://google.com').status_code == 200,
    step=60,
    poll_forever=True)
```

If this returns true,is there a way to access the response body in order to get the specific fields?In my case it is returning a json response

Comment: you can just get the content from the python requests itself with request.get('http://google.com').content, i'm not familiar with python polling so this is  a suggestion [request response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18810889/11225821)

Comment: what is `pooling2.poll` ? How did you create it ? What module did you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can assing `poll()` result to variable and it will have value returned by `lambda`

```
result = polling2.poll(lambda: requests.get('http://google.com').status_code == 200, 
                       step=60, 
                       poll_forever=True)
```

But in current code `lambda` returns `True` and `result` will be `True` and there will be no access to `requests`

But you can write it in different way using `check_success=` to test status

```
import requests
import polling

def test(response):
    return response.status_code == 200

result = polling.poll(lambda: requests.get('http://google.com'), 
                      step=60, 
                      poll_forever=True, 
                      check_success=test)

print(result.text)
```

Now `lambda` returns `response` and `poll` sends this `response` to function `test` which check `status_code`. If `test` will return `True` then it will assing `response` to  `result` and you can use `.text`, `.content` or `.json()`

---

I found it in source code of [polling.py](https://github.com/justiniso/polling/blob/master/polling.py)

---

**EDIT:** It shows how to use `collect_value=`. But `queue` gets all values except last one which you have in `result`. SO it collects results for responses which had status different then `200` (or error messages if they rised errors).

```
import requests
import polling
import queue

def test(response):
    return response.status_code == 200

my_queue = queue.Queue()

result = polling.poll(lambda: requests.get('http://google.com'), 
                      step=60, 
                      poll_forever=True, 
                      check_success=test,
                      collect_value=my_queue)

if my_queue.empty():
    print('empty')
else:
    while not my_queue.empty():
        print(my_queue.get())

#print(result.text)
```

Comment: Thanks,that is what I was looking for. Do you have any idea, how to use collect_value queue in this method?

Comment: You have to create own `queue.Queue()` and use it with `collec_value=`. After running you can use `.empty()` and `.get()` to get values from your queue. But queue will have all values except last one which you get in `results`.

Comment: I added example code with `Queue`. But it is empty because first `requests.get()` has status `200`. It would need function which few times gives different status.

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I have a specific need in my program.My pub/sub url holds a queue which has several messages. I always want to get the most recent message using polling function. Can I acheive this using collect_value or is there a different way to do this? please help

Comment: to get most recent you have to get all messages from queue and last message will be the most recent - `while not my_queue.empty(): last = my_queue.get()`> I don't know why to use `polling` for this