# How to parse a list of files from Sharepoint

Tags: python, json, api, rest

I am using sharepy for the first time. Here is my code:

```
import sharepy
import json

# (1) Authenticate
s = sharepy.connect("https://my_company.sharepoint.com",\
username="my_name@my_company.co.uk", password="my_password")

# (2) Get file information
r = s.get("https://my_company.sharepoint.com/Projects")
print(r)
```

Which gives the output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

So the request has been successful. However I am unsure how to handle this request and get the list of files from this request. Any ideas?

Comment: Here are couple ways u can try, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18810889/4985099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output status suggests that its a success response. So you can now use that `response` in `r` and parse it to `json` and dump the `json` response to another file.

The code below taken from [here](https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-sharepoint-with-python/) illustrates exactly how you can get details on the files.

#### Get file information

```
data = r.json()
file = open("sharepoint.json", "w")
file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
print("json file has been generated")
```

#### Download file

```
r = s.getfile("https:// example.sharepoint.com/GroupSites/HR/_api/web\
/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/GroupSites/HR/Shared Documents/Team.xlsx')/$value"\
, filename = 'team.xlsx')
print("File Downloaded")
```