# get site data python

Tags: python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I have link "https://uchebnik.mos.ru/app_player/204597".
I need to get url with "https://learningapps.org/show.php?id=pxnu062wj20&fullscreen=1" or "pxnu062wj20".
I have found this data in network:
[image]

And in "sources" tab:
[image]

It is desirable that this be done without using a webdriver.
Also, i can use requests, requests_html, urllib3.

Comment: That is great. However, what is your current progress on this? Could you post any code that you tried and it fails for some reason?

Comment: I don't have any code that relates to this. I tried to receive html page content, send GET requests, but I don't know how to get what I need.

Comment: You can try this yourself `https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/`

Comment: How can the link to the documentation of this module help me? I've already tried looking for answers but couldn't find anything.

Comment: We help you code, we don't do the coding for you. So please show your best attempt so we can help you out. Make sure to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), now I get an error message when opening the site ("нет доступа к приложению")

Comment: @mooncdx, The documentation will help in getting started with a library to try something out yourself, rather than pushing the work to the fellow stackoverflow people to do for you. In terms of examples, you can take a look at other stackoverflow questions themselves: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140661/what-s-the-best-way-to-get-an-http-response-code-from-a-url`, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810777/how-do-i-read-a-response-from-python-requests`